# How to use iphone default ringtone sound and continuous vibration upto 30 second in push notification,

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, xcode7, payload

How to play iphone phone ringtone sound and continuously vibration,from APNS push notification.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sounds you can play with a push notification are either the default alert tone for the device, or a sound that you've included as part of your application bundle. The vibration will also use the systems default vibration scheme, which I don't think can be extended for that long.

Comment: yes ,I have added custom tone to my application bundle, But I was thinking to play System default Iphone tone When Incoming call arrive, I have seen this type of work on Whatsapp Imcoming Call,they play system Default Sound,When Incoming VOIP call,through Push Notification

Comment: @SAURABHSANWAL Did you find solution for the problem.